# Using Java api, how to find out the memo attached to a payment operation?

Tags: java-sdk

I can use the following code from example to receive payment event from public horizon.  But the pos variable doesn't have memo information.  Where should I get the memo from a certain paymente operation response?

```
paymentsRequest.stream(new EventListener<OperationResponse>() {
    @Override   public void onEvent(OperationResponse payment) {
    // Record the paging token so we can start from here next time.
    savePagingToken(payment.getPagingToken());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memo can only be attached to a **transaction**, not **operation**. So you should rather listen to transactions stream or load a corresponding transaction by hash once a payment received.

The first option is better because transaction response contains XDR from which all related operations can be deserialized, while the second variant requires additional horizon requests.

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to use transaction with "now" cursor but the stream stuck for a while and after that, onEvent was not called when a transaction happened.  If I don't use "now", everything is fine, except it processed every transactions.  Do you have such experience?

Comment: Plus, I got getMemo(), but only showed somethign like org.stellar.skdk.MemoText@5ea8cf9f.  How do I change to text?

Comment: There is another option. Prepare request builder for transactions, set limit to 1 and execute it. Once you get the response, you have a `paging_token` for the streaming mode. Create one more request builder and specify the obtained paging_token as a cursor. Such approach requires two requests instead of one, but 100% works.

Comment: `MemoText` is a class (check https://stellar.github.io/java-stellar-sdk/org/stellar/sdk/MemoText.html), use `getText()` method to retrieve the content.